# Cannot execute as the user 'username' AS IF it was an orphaned user. But user is WITHOUT LOGIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have restored a database to a different server.  The following errors do not occur in the original database.

I have a username WITHOUT LOGIN.  Username is used in EXECUTE AS for a procedure. In the restored database, when attempting to execute the stored procedure, I get the following error

```
Cannot execute as the user 'username', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

This is NOT a traditional orphaned user because it is WITHOUT LOGIN. It acts AS IF it is orphaned. But, The user cannot be re-aligned with a LOGIN because there is no LOGIN to realign.  In researching, I find this question asked and all responses reference orphaned users.  For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798206/error-with-sql-server-execute-as

This Microsoft reference also pops up with the above error, but it is purely orphaned users with LOGINs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16

How might I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have permission to impersonate the user?

Comment: Yes.  The user calling the stored procedure has permissions.

Comment: Run this query to verify the proc execution context user is as expected: `SELECT USER_NAME(execute_as_principal_id) FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.YourProc');`

Comment: @DanGuzman That rocks!!  Thank you.  Yes, it shows the correct value for USER_NAME(execute_as_principal_id)